# DataTableAdapter Report Viewer C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

После компиляции приложения, не работает отчет в reportViewer если рядом с файлом .exe не лежит XML файл, в котором при компиляции прописывается сервер, логин и пароль. 
**Код запуска отчета**:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 this.DataTable4TableAdapter.Fill(this.DandDDataSet.DataTable4, dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString());
 this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
 }
```

Я не хочу что бы этот файл попадал к конечным пользователям программы. 
 Возможно ли указать строку подключения внутри? Если да, прошу пример. 
Ранее я отчет делал так:

```
DandDDataSet m = new DandDDataSet();
 cn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("запрос", cn);
      da.Fill(m, m.Tables[0].TableName);
   ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", m.Tables[0]);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Но мне кажется что это костыль.

Comment: xml-файл - это файл отчета, где описано и подключение к БД и именно поэтому там логин/пароль?

Comment: @kvvk, этот файл генерится автоматом при компиляции программы. Я решил проблему вторым способом, который я описал.